# Insert duplicate rows to a DataFrame using a list of desired repetitions

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to duplicate a dataframe using the index of another. For example, imagine the following:

```
basket = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["food_type", "food", "qty"], data=[
    ["fruit" ,  "apple",   1],
    ["fruit" ,  "pear",    1],
    ["fruit" ,  "banana",  1],
    ["veggie",  "carrot",  1],
    ["veggie",  "lettuce", 1]])

basket.set_index(["food_type", "food"], inplace=True)
```

[image]

I am trying to duplicate these rows using a list of people so that I achieve the following:

```
target_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["person", "food_type", "food", "qty"]
                        ).set_index(["person", "food_type", "food"])

people = ["jane", "john", "joan"]
for person in people:
    basket_copy = basket.copy()
    basket_copy["person"] = person
    basket_copy.set_index("person", append=True, inplace=True)
    target_df = target_df.append(basket_copy)
```

[image]

This solution works but seems very clunky. Is there a more natural way to do this in Python? I am imagining some kind of merge between the `basket` dataframe and an array of the `people`.

Comment: person and food are swapped...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), and [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = pd.concat(basket.assign(person=p) for p in people).set_index('person', append=True)
```

The resulting output:

```
                          qty
food_type food    person     
fruit     apple   jane      1
          pear    jane      1
          banana  jane      1
veggie    carrot  jane      1
          lettuce jane      1
fruit     apple   john      1
          pear    john      1
          banana  john      1
veggie    carrot  john      1
          lettuce john      1
fruit     apple   joan      1
          pear    joan      1
          banana  joan      1
veggie    carrot  joan      1
          lettuce joan      1
```

Answer (score 2):

***construct `pd.MultiIndex` + `np.repeat`***

```
people = ['jane', 'john', 'joan']
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [[t, f, p] for p in people for (t, f) in basket.index],
    names=basket.index.names + ['person']
)

pd.DataFrame(
    basket.qty.values.repeat(len(people)),
    mux, ['qty']
)
```

***another `pd.concat` option***
*though not as clean*

```
people = ['jane', 'john', 'joan']
d1 = pd.concat([basket.stack()] * len(people), axis=1, keys=people)
d1.rename_axis('person', 1).stack().unstack(-2)
```

***Both yield***

```
                          qty
food_type food    person     
fruit     apple   jane      1
                  john      1
                  joan      1
          banana  jane      1
                  john      1
                  joan      1
          pear    jane      1
                  john      1
                  joan      1
veggie    carrot  jane      1
                  john      1
                  joan      1
          lettuce jane      1
                  john      1
                  joan      1
```

---

***naive time testing***
*over given data*

[image]

Comment: Accepting the other answer because the code is slightly shorter, but I like the idea of using `np.repeat`. Thank you!